# Is there a way to read a plot as a matrix of pixels without saving it on disk?

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to have an R plot as a matrix of pixels. I can simply save and read it again as a bitmap. But is there a faster way to do this directly without saving the plot first?

```
library(readbitmap)

tmp = tempfile()
bmp(tmp)
plot(1)
dev.off()
result = read.bitmap(tmp)
```